# How can I get the largest value from an integer array in a dictionary of arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to get the largest value in a dictionary of arrays and I need also get the key of that array.

This is how I get the largest value:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
]
var largest = 0

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
var largest_kind : String? =nil
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            largest_kind = kind
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use max method in your dictionary values and get the maximum value from the resulting tuple values:

```
if let result = interestingNumbers.max(by: {$0.value.max() ?? 0 < $1.value.max() ?? 0}),
    let maxValue = result.value.max() {
    print(result.key)    // "Square\n"
    print(result.value)  // "[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]\n"
    print(maxValue)      // 25
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Swift function's for that.

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
    ]

if let value = interestingNumbers.map ({ ($0, $1.max() ?? 0) }).max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 }) {
    print(value.0, value.1) // Square 25
}
```

**Let's go with step by step**

First I have created array of `tuple` with type `[(String, Int)]`, with first place it will store group and on second place it will store max value from its corresponding array.

```
let array = interestingNumbers.map ({ ($0, $1.max() ?? 0) })
//[("Fibonacci", 8), ("Square", 25), ("Prime", 13)]
```

Now find the max `Int` from the array of tuple.

```
if let value = array.max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 }) {
    print(value.0, value.1) //Will print group here it is "Square 25"
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant :)

Comment: @IvensDenner Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a tuple to hold the largest value?

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]

var largest: (kind: String?, number: Int) = (nil, 0)

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest.number {
            largest = (kind, number)
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be further simplified to:

```
var largest: (kind: String?, number: Int) = (nil, 0)

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    let max = numbers.max() ?? 0
    if max > largest.number {
        largest = (kind, max)
    }
}
```

Another method is to flatten the values first into a `(kind, number)` sequence:

```
let flattened = interestingNumbers
    .map { (kind, numbers) in numbers.map { (kind, $0) } }
    .joined()

let largest = flattened.max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1} )
print(largest)
```

or you can realize that only the maximum value in every array is the most important, therefore :

```
let largestPerKind = interestingNumbers
    .map { (kind, numbers) in (kind, numbers.max() ?? 0) }

let largest = largestPerKind.max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1} )
print(largest)
```

Comment: pretty straight forward thanks. although i don't understand whats going on in the flatten method you stated...

Comment: @Timi.O The first step generates an array of arrays of 2-tuples `[[("Prime", 2), ("Prime", 3), ...], [("Fibonacci", 1), ("Fibonacci", 1)...], ...]`, the (`.joined()`) call flattens it into one flat array `[("Prime", 2), ("Prime", 3), ..., ("Fibonacci", 1), ("Fibonacci", 1)...]`